# Добавить button back в диалоговое окно jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui

Как можно добавить кнопку "назад" (или вернуться на предыдущую страницу) в диалоговом окне на jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  ...
  buttons: {
    Back: function() {
      window.history.back();
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-role="page" id="mypage" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Назад">
```